# tranferring android framebuffer to another devices

Tags: android, p2p, framebuffer

I'm planning to make a program to connect each other and control thier android device

yes, It's sort of remote control native application.

so, I'm wondering about that the frame buffer in android can be tranfered by streaming technologies such as Gstreamer or Web RTC

I've seen a few postings about this but it didn't make sense..

I think .. it is possible to move the framebuffer as a image file and to show the image on another device . if my program do that repeatedly, two android devices can be sharing their screen so it makes the screen issues can be solved on my project

please give me any solutions for it

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

You need to root the Android phone to get the frame buffers.